# R data.table, Replacing each cell value if greater than 0 with 1

Tags: r, data.table

I have R data.table
There are 25 columns, 1st column is ID, 24 columns are integer variables. There are close to 1Million rows. How do i convert all these non-zero values to 1

```
Custid  A   B  C
123     0   8  0
124     0   0  6
```

Should become

```
Custid  A   B  C
123     0   1  0
124     0   0  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An efficient option is the `set` function which replace in place.  Loop through the columns using a `for` loop and `set` the 'value' to 1 where the element is not equal to 0 by specifying the 'i' and 'j' index.

```
for(j in 2:ncol(dt)){
   set(dt, i= which(dt[[j]]!=0), j=j, value =1)
}
dt
#   Custid A B C
#1:    123 0 1 0
#2:    124 0 0 1
```

---

Or another option is with `lapply` by looping over the Subset of Data.table after specifying the `.SDcols`

```
dt[, names(dt)[-1] := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(x!=0)), .SDcols = 2:ncol(dt)]
```

Comment: That worked fast enough. As soon as I saw the for loop I had lost hope. But it worked out well, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your data.table is called 'dt',

```
df = as.data.frame(dt)
df[,-1] = (df[,-1] != 0)*1
```

works. the `-1` index indicates the non-inclusion of the first column, and then inside the parenthesis returns a true or false statement and `*1` ensures that the result is returned in numeric form.

If you want you can turn it back to a data.table.

```
dt = data.table(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

this should also work

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {ifelse(any(x > 0), 1, 0)})
```